# Launch WPF Application by Instantiate App.xaml vs. MainWindow.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In order to launch a WPF application from a Win Form App I’ve found two ways. One is by instantiate App.xaml:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    var t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var app = new App();
        App.ResourceAssembly = app.GetType().Assembly;
        app.InitializeComponent();
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    });

    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
}
```

And the other one is by instantiate MainWindow.xaml.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
   var t = new Thread(() =>
   {
       MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
       window.Closed += (s2, e2) => window.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
       window.Show();
       System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
   });

   t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
   t.Start();
}
```

Could you please help me to understand what the difference between both approaches is?

Comment: I would say that neither of those examples is in fact "launching a WPF application". The word "launch" is typically used to describe a whole new process. You are simply opening a new window. It is not clear from your question what your requirements are, but it seems to me that actually creating a new process is the best approach. If you need to mix Winforms and WPF in the same process, there are "hosting" mechanisms you can use to allow Winforms and WPF components to interoperate in the same thread.

Comment: In other words, I doubt either of the examples you have is in fact what you really ought to be doing. But there's not enough context in your question to know what specifically you _should_ be doing. The question is just too broad as stated.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I have an existing VSTO Excel project and I’ve recently created a separate WPF project using SQL LocalDB and Entity Framework. Now I am trying to move this WPF project into the same solution with the VSTO project and to open the WPF window from a button on Excel Ribbon. Surprisingly it is not that easy. Requirements are: when the user click again on the button to bring to front the WPF window, or to re-open it, if it was closed in the meantime. Also to exchange some string information between both projects.